# How do I find distinct values of one field based on date range? Elasticsearch 6.3

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-6

I have a field `cid` that I need to find the distinct values of.
But I want those `cid` that satisfy my date range constraint. What I mean is, I want distinct `cid` that were added to my Elasticsearch Database during the given time range.

I have tried many approaches, most of them just return all values and don't aggregate.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "daterange": {
            "range": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "ranges": [
                        {"from": "2019-05-02", "to": "2019-05-03"}
                    ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "result": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "cid.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source":"cid"
}
```

I expect the distinct values of `cid` but what I get is all values that comply with the time range.

Update:

Val's answer works after changing my URL from `/index/search?size=100` to `/index/search`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it this way, i.e. add the date `range` as a query to reduce the document set, and then run the `terms` aggregation only on the documents that fall into that date range:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2019-05-02",
        "lt": "2019-05-03"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cid.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work. It returns all documents based on time range. So basically no aggregation. Maybe because I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3?

Comment: I also didnt do any mapping whatsoever. These logs come directly from logstash.

Comment: Aggregations come at the end... maybe add `size: 0` so you only get the aggregations (see my updated answer)

Comment: Still the same issue. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you update your question with your index mapping?

Comment: Thanks, it works! The issue was my url endpoint was `/index/search?size=100` which I was using for my previous API testing because only 10 results were being delivered by default. After i removed `size` param, everything works.